# How filter previous record if one field is same in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have records like below:

```
ID            Date              Title        User 
1   2019-04-29 14:15:55.567      A           1222
2   2019-04-29 14:25:13.530      A           1222
3   2019-04-29 15:17:07.210      A           1222
4   2019-04-29 16:05:49.067      B           1048
5   2019-04-29 16:36:37.330      C           681
6   2019-04-29 16:37:16.250      C           681
7   2019-04-29 16:37:49.160      D           681
8   2019-04-29 16:38:48.803      C           681
```

I want to check each record with previous record and if Title of both is same , ignore previous.

I want see result like this:

```
ID            Date              Title        User 
3   2019-04-29 15:17:07.210      A           1222
4   2019-04-29 16:05:49.067      B           1048
6   2019-04-29 16:37:16.250      C           681
7   2019-04-29 16:37:49.160      D           681
8   2019-04-29 16:38:48.803      C           681
```

Comment: Why is 3 there and 6 instead of 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(title) over (order by id) as next_title
      from t
     ) t
where next_title is null or next_title <> title;
```

You want to use `lead()` because you want the *most* recent value in each group.  You would use `lag()` if you wanted the earliest value.

I'm not sure if the ordering should be by `id` or the `date` column.  For your sample data, they are equivalent.

Comment: @Hossein . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  It seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

use `lag()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d4c0b2d28039b025d8be9c9c6317ced)**

```
select * from
(
select *, lag(title) over(order by date desc) as prevtitle
from tablename
)A where prevtitle is null or title<>prevtitle
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  dateval             title   userid
3   29/04/2019 15:17:07   A      1222
4   29/04/2019 16:05:49   B      1048
6   29/04/2019 16:37:16   C      681
7   29/04/2019 16:37:49   D      681
8   29/04/2019 16:38:48   C      681
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAG` function for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
         , LAG(title) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS prev_title
    FROM t
) AS x
WHERE title <> prev_title
```